# Launchpad oneboxing doesn't work for bugs specifying a package

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, onebox

Chat supports oneboxing for Launchpad bugs for projects other than Ubuntu. For example, linking to https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/889421 shows the bug description.

However, bugs in Ubuntu use a different URL scheme, which also specifies the package name. I tried linking to [Launchpad bug #612986](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fortune-mod/+bug/612986), `https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fortune-mod/+bug/612986`, in chat. It does not onebox. Currently, to get it to work, you have to manually edit the link to `https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/612986`.

This nerfs the oneboxing, since most Ubuntu bugs redirect to a URL containing the package.

The fix is to also recognize Launchpad URLs containing `+source/fortune-mod/+bug/`.

Answer (score 3):

This is fixed and should be out in the next deploy.